# Problems After Android update

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I have a Samsung S6, I've recently (2 days ago) received a notification for a new update rolled out by Samsung which installed instantly. However, from that time i am in trouble with charging my phone. I am unable to charge it even if I've tried many Samsung original chargers. I get a gray battery icon, and i can barely switch on the phone (with 0% charge)

Do you have any solution for me other than reset my phone?

Comment: Have you considered contacting Samsung support? As there were similar issues with an update on the S7, they should have experience with this. Apart from that: Does it charge when switched off? In that state the OS shouldn't interfere. Also try while booted into recovery or "Download" ("Odin") mode. Does that make any difference? Not that I knew what to do if it did, but that are things you could tell the service, might trigger an idea from them.

Comment: thanks @Izzy for your comment. when the phone is switched off i get only a gray battery icon charging and it stuck on it even for hours. i've tried to let the phone charging in the recovery mode but no difference as i switch on i get 0% battery. BUT what's strange i keep getting command error if a choose any option i recovery mode. I am thinking of rooting the phone would it be a good idea?

Comment: Not when stuck at 0% battery (if it's really there and not just showing wrong). I'd strongly suggest contacting customer service. If it doesn't even charge when switched off, I'd think it should not be related to the OS but something else got borked.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking your charger, if you buy a charger doctor (cost about £1). You can see if you have 5V and any current flow.

You could also check your battery voltage for around >3.6V - very carefully using a DMM. Those are suggestions I can think of from a hardware perspective.

I try to avoid updates, but it seems hard to believe it would cause that much trouble!?

Comment: thanks for the replay but the recent update triggered the same problem for many S7 owners. i can't remove or test the battery without disassembling the phone which i try to avoid

Comment: Ah I see, my answer probably won't be of much help then. Hopefully Samsung get something sorted out soon for those with the battery drain issues. All sounds pretty bad.